# What library do I need to use "File" type with selenium?

Tags: java, file, selenium

I want to use Selenium to control Firefox, but I want to control a custom profile of Firefox.

I found this:

```
    File profileDirectory = new File(profileDirectory);
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But the `File` symbol is not found and  I don't know what library contains it.

Comment: If you load this code into an IDE like Eclipse, you will see that unknown keywords like File will have red underlines, and you can right click it, and it will import `java.io.File;` for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`java.io.File` is part of the standard Java library.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

The following should allow your code to compile:

```
import java.io.File;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a man a fish, Teach a man to fish...

If you do a google search for "java File"  It will take you to this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

The very top of that page displays a miniature tree which tells you that in Java version 1.4.2, the symbol: "File" is an Object that is extended by `java.io.File`